# Dense Subgroup Of Reals with addition

Tags: group-theory

let $G$ be a non-trivial subgroup of $ (R,+) $. Prove that $G$ to be a dense or $(nZ)$.

I know this result is true of course .But problem is to prove it.
Please hint to prove it.

Comment: So just to be clear, you need to allow $n$ to be any real. I need to think a bit more for a good hint, but it seems like one could start by assuming the group not to be dense, take an open interval intersecting the group trivially and use this to find a suitable $n$ by translating the set to become something like $(0,n)$ (by also making it as large as possible). But there are a lot of details there I am not quite certain will work out.

Comment: You can also define $n=\inf\big(G\cap(0,\infty)\big)$ and split into two cases, $n>0$ and $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $G=x\Bbb Z$ for some $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, then $|x|$ is the smallest positive member of $G$. If, on the other hand, $G$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, then clearly $G$ has no smallest positive member. This suggests the following approach.

- Show that if $G$ has a smallest positive element $x$, then $G=x\Bbb Z$.
- Show that if $G\cap(0,\to)$ does not have a smallest positive element, then $G$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.

For both of these it is helpful to show that if $x\in G$, then $x\Bbb Z\subseteq G$.